# Solr internal document processing

Tags: solr

I am newbie to solr, today I have created my first solr collection. I want to analysis my documents fields storage and how solr internally process document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr has inbuilt document analysis feature, check at [solr wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Analysis+Screen), it is very well documented. 
It help to identify how a text value would split into multiple words during query and Indexing for a field or field type.